# Can't get a tableviewcontroller to reload after adding a new element

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I've been trying this for a while now and it is completely frustrating me but here is a brief summary of what I am trying to do. I have a LocationTableViewController with a plus button on the top right to add new locations to the table view. When that happens, I enter the LocationEditViewController where I can enter the name of the location I want to add. After adding my text and hitting the save location button I want the code to bring me back to the LocationTableViewController and there in my table I see my newly added location. Posted below is the code of the two view controllers. Hopefully you guys can help me thanks a ton!!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Location.h"
#import "User.h"

@interface LocationEditViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) Location *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *user;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *locationNameField;

- (void)saveLocation:(id) sender;

@end


#import "LocationEditViewController.h"

@interface LocationEditViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationEditViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Edit";
        self.location = [[Location alloc] init];
        self.user = [[User alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UILabel *locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    locationLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20,15,50,30);
    locationLabel.text = @"Name:";
    [self.view addSubview:locationLabel];

    self.locationNameField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.locationNameField.frame = CGRectMake(15,50,290,30);
    self.locationNameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
    self.locationNameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    self.locationNameField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.locationNameField];

    UIButton *saveLocationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    saveLocationButton.frame = CGRectMake(15,400,290,50);
    [saveLocationButton setTitle:@"Save Location" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [saveLocationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:saveLocationButton];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)saveLocation:(id)sender {
    self.location.name = self.locationNameField.text;

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.user.createdLocations];
    [tempArray addObject:self.location];
    self.user.createdLocations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Added"
                                                    message:@"This location is now accessable in the locations tab"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[1] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.user.createdLocations.count]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somethingAddedNotification" object:nil];
    }];
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Here is the LocationTableViewController code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "User.h"

@interface LocationTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *locations;
@property (strong, nonatomic) User *user;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id _observer;

- (void) addLocationPressed;

@end



#import "LocationTableViewController.h"
#import "LocationEditViewController.h"
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@interface LocationTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Locations";
        self.user = [[User alloc] init];
        UIBarButtonItem *addLocationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addLocationPressed)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addLocationButton;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Location *loc = [[Location alloc] init];
    //self.user.createdLocations = @[loc];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void) addLocationPressed
{
    LocationEditViewController *locationEditVC = [[LocationEditViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:locationEditVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.user.createdLocations.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.user.createdLocations[indexPath.row] name];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.user.createdLocations[indexPath.row] name]);

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    LocationViewController *locationVC = [[LocationViewController alloc] init];
    locationVC.location = self.user.createdLocations[indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    __observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"somethingAddedNotification"
                                                                  object:nil
                                                                   queue:nil
                                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:__observer];
}
```

For additional information here is the user class where I am getting the array

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Location.h"

@interface User : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) Location *profilePhoto;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *createdLocations;


-(id) initWithTitle: (Location *) aLoc
             detail: (NSString *) aDet
           filename: (NSArray *) aLocList;

//-(id)initWithJSON;
//+(NSString *)getPathToArchive;

//+(User *)getUser;
//+(void)saveUser:(User *)aUser;

@end

#import "User.h"
#import "Location.h"

@implementation User

- (id)init;
{
    self = [self initWithTitle: [[Location alloc] init]
                        detail: @"Temp"
                      filename: [[NSArray alloc] init]];
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithTitle: (Location *) aLoc
             detail: (NSString *) aDet
           filename: (NSArray *) aLocList
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.profilePhoto = aLoc;
        self.location = aDet;
        self.createdLocations = aLocList;
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

and the Locations class if necessary

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Location : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *filename;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *thumbnail;

-(id) initWithTitle: (NSString *) aTitle
             detail: (NSString *) aDetail
           filename: (NSString *) aFilename
          thumbnail: (NSString *) aThumbnail;

@end

#import "Location.h"

@implementation Location

-(id)init
{
    self = [self initWithTitle:@"Title"
                        detail:@"Detail"
                      filename:@"placeholder.jpg"
                     thumbnail:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle
            detail:(NSString *)aDetail
          filename:(NSString *)aFilename
         thumbnail:(NSString *)aThumbnail
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = aTitle;
        self.detail = aDetail;
        self.filename = aFilename;
        self.thumbnail = aThumbnail;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Hopefully you guys can help me! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Before I read through 4 files of code that doesn't work, are you calling `reloadData`?

Comment: yep i am in one of the viewwillappear method

Comment: This might or might have anything to do with the issue, but using a notification in this way is a poor choice. The two controllers can see each other so they should communicate directly. A delegate / protocol architecture would be appropriate, or you could just have them know about each other directly. In this way you can hand info back and forth.

Comment: be aware that accessing self.tableView in the block creates a strong reference - use the __weak modifier to make a weak pointer to self before accessing in the block, for [self.tableView reloadData];. And I agree with matt about notification.

Comment: so do you possibly have any guides on delegates or protocols that are easily understood cause I attempted it and totally botched it haha

Comment: @user3667232 I explain it a bit in this answer, about half way through. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51158/model-to-handle-all-the-data-networking-from-foursquare-api-in-ios/51174#51174

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a breakpoint on...

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

...in your observer block? Does it get hit? Separately, Drew Crawford is wary of that API you are using (http://sealedabstract.com/code/nsnotificationcenter-with-blocks-considered-harmful/).

Comment: I have it doesn't cause any problems and does get called its just not doing anything

Comment: Is the tableView property non-nil? That's always a good thing to check when an object is sent a message but does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment said, this is definitely a problem, and may in fact be the root cause. You must use the `__weak` reference inside the block or else NSNotificationCenter owns a strong reference to self and self owns a strong reference to NSNotificationCenter, and you have a retain cycle.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    __weak LocationTableViewController *weakSelf = self;

    __observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"somethingAddedNotification"
                                                                  object:nil
                                                                   queue:nil
                                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
    {
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: hmm i tried that and it seems to change nothing but that will definitely help with anything

Comment: Make sure you keep it, otherwise you have a memory leak and it will eventually cause your app to be killed by the OS.